# Checkbox List in ASP.NET MVC. I cant retrieve data to a IEnumerable or List

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have a problem with an application using ASP.NET MVC 4, I'm trying to show in a view to create an entity called CompositePiece, a List of items (which are CompositePieces too) from my database, then, the user could select one or more of them, and the items selected would be in a collection in the 'father' CompositePiece, at first, my class CompositePiece:

```
namespace Garbi.Models{
  public class CompositePiece
    {
    [Key]
    public int CompositePieceId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduzca un nombre para la pieza")]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre de la pieza")]
    public string CompositePieceName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompositePiece> Components { get; set; }

    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int LevelOfHierarchy { get; set; }

    public CompositePiece(PieceModel model)
    {
        this.Components = new List<CompositePiece>();
        this.CompositePieceName = model.PieceModelName;
        LevelOfHierarchy = 0;
    }

    public CompositePiece()
    {
        this.Components = new List<CompositePiece>();
        LevelOfHierarchy = 0;
    }

    public CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel ToCreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel(string processName)
    {
        return new CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel
        {
            CompositePieceName = this.CompositePieceName,
            ProcessId = this.ProcessId,
            ProcessName = processName
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

I have created a ViewModel to pass the data to a view, the ViewModel is:

```
namespace Garbi.ViewModels.CompositePieces
{
  public class CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel
  {

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduzca un nombre para la pieza")]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre de la pieza")]
    public string CompositePieceName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Components { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedComponentsId { get; set; }

    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }

    public int LevelOfHierarchy { get; set; }

    public void AddComponentsList(IEnumerable<CompositePiece> dataProvider, CompositePiece fatherPiece)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> auxList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (CompositePiece piece in dataProvider)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text=piece.CompositePieceName,
                Value = piece.CompositePieceId.ToString(),
                Selected = fatherPiece.Components.Contains(piece)
            };
            auxList.Add(item);
        }
        Components = new List<SelectListItem>(auxList);
    }

    public CompositePiece ToCompositePiece()
    {
        return new CompositePiece
        {
            CompositePieceName = this.CompositePieceName,
            LevelOfHierarchy = this.LevelOfHierarchy,
            ProcessId = this.ProcessId
        };
    }
  }
}
```

Mi View is:

```
@model Garbi.ViewModels.CompositePieces.CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear pieza compuesta";
 }

<div class="advertise">Crear pieza compuesta para @Model.ProcessName</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Nueva pieza compuesta</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompositePieceName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompositePieceName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompositePieceName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Components)
        {
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.Selected, item.Value)
                @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.Value)
                @item.Text
                @Html.HiddenFor(i => item)
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Components)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LevelOfHierarchy)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProcessId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProcessName)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

<div class="back">
    @Html.NavLink("Process_"+@Model.ProcessId, "Page1", "Volver")
</div>
}
```

And at last, I want to show you the methods of my controller, they are:

```
public ActionResult ComposePieces(int processId)
    {
        context = new EFDbContext();
        Process process = context.ProcessesPaginable.FindEntityById(processId);
        CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel model = new CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel
        {
            ProcessId = process.ProcessId,
            ProcessName = process.ProcessName,
            LevelOfHierarchy = 0
        };
        IEnumerable<CompositePiece> totalPieces = context.CompositePiecesPaginable.FindAllCompositePiecesOfAProcess(processId).Where(p => p.LevelOfHierarchy == 0);
        model.AddComponentsList(totalPieces, model.ToCompositePiece());
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ComposePieces(CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel model)
    {
        context = new EFDbContext();
        CompositePiece compositePieceToAdd = model.ToCompositePiece();
        CompositePiece aux;
        [...]
    }
```

My problem comes when I call the view, I can see perfectly the collection of items, each of them with its checkbox, but when I check some of them, put the CompositePiece's name and click at Submit button, I recover the new CreateOrEditCompositePieceViewModel with its new name, but my attribute Components is empty. I think I am having a mistake of base, but I don't know where is the error, and why I have this problem.

Thank you for your time and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same Problem as you do.

When I get the postback, the Navigation properties are not returning, even thought I select them on the form, or hid them.

I think this Problem has to do with the Attribute being virtual, and by so it uses lazy loading.

One Thing that I tried that showed promising, but still did^'t get the Job done is if you add the:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Components);
```

Before your foreach Loop.
What happens is that when you look on you postback, you will find the components there, it won't be null anymore, but still the list will be empty, but I think the solution is on this direction.

Anyways, enough of this.
I'm about to do a way around this that should work.
What you do, you create a viewmodel
with your class
plus list of each of the virtual lists

something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public MyModelView(CompositePiece cp)
   {
      CompositePiece = cp;
      Components = cp.Components.ToList();
   }
   public CompositePiece CompositePiece { get; set; }
   public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

I just saw that on your class you create a list of itself, you probably shouldn't do that.
That's not how you create linked lists in C#

So, if instead you do like this example, you will create an instance of you virtual lists, and this should solve the Problem.

Good luck.